# Freed cloned skb (using skb_clone) will free the original skb?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I want to enqueue a skb buff in more than one queue. So I thought of using the cloning option.
Now my question is if I do kfree_skb on the **cloned** skb, will it release the original skb, or just drop one reference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[`kfree_skb()`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.12/net/core/skbuff.c#L629) will do the right thing with cloned skbuffs, i.e. free the skbuff structure itself but not the data, if it is still referenced by other skbuffs.

This is done on [`skb_release_data()`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.12/net/core/skbuff.c#L506), which checks if the skbuff is not a clone, or if this was the last  reference to `skb->data` (done in a roundabout way to support headerless skbuffs, which hold references to the payload part of `skb->data` (higher 16 bits of `skb->dataref`), besides the usual reference to the whole of `skb->data`).

Answer (score 2):

When a clone of an skb is made, a new memory is allocated for cloned sk_buff and all of the `struct sk_buff` members of the clone are private to the clone. 
The data i.e packet, however, is shared between the original SKB and it's clone. So `sk_buff` structure only is copied to new memory. If you free the original skb, then data will be lost if dataref count is zero. Here data is your packet.

If you dont want to loose data on freeing up of any of skb, use `skb_copy` instead of `skb_clone`: `skb_copy` will copy both the sk_buff and the packet to new memory area.

EDIT: editing the previous reply with some correction.

Comment: I want to free the cloned one, but I am afraid that it will also free the original skb. There's no chance in my code that the original one will be deleted before the cloned one.

Will the original get freed as well?

I want to avoid skb_copy, because it's an expensive operation.

Comment: Original will not be lost... skb is not freed until dataref of skb is zero. when the skb is cloned, its clonned flag is set; The data may be released only when it is assured that no entity holds a pointer to the data.  If the cloned flag is not set it is assumed that whoever is attempting to free the sk_buff header is the only 
entity that held a pointer to the data.